# javascript mirror dropdown selection in another dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have two forms on my page. One is hidden initially. Later, after the first form is submitted the first is hidden and the second similar but more compact form is displayed instead.

I want the second form to be loaded with the same values that were submitted in the first form, which I have accomplished, except for the dropdown, which is causing me issues.

What I'm trying is as follows:

```
<select
    name        = "chooseRep"
    id          = "chooseRep1"
    data-param  = "required"
    data-desc   = "report"
    onchange    = "document.getElementById('chooseRep2').options[document.getElementById('chooseRep2').selectedIndex]=this.options[this.selectedIndex]">

    <option value="">Select...</option>
    <option value="pAndL">Profit &amp; Loss</option>
    <option value="balSheet">Balance Sheet</option>

</select>
```

This doesn't seem to have any effect. I do have Jquery available, so that is an option if someone knows how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should set the value,

```
<select
    name        = "chooseRep"
    id          = "chooseRep1"
    data-param  = "required"
    data-desc   = "report"
    onchange    = "document.getElementById('chooseRep2').value = this.value;">

    <option value="">Select...</option>
    <option value="pAndL">Profit &amp; Loss</option>
    <option value="balSheet">Balance Sheet</option>

</select>
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it and it's not working. Firebug says, "document.getElementById(...) is null"

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit hasty! It was because my ID of the second dropdown was "chooseRep1". Updated that and now working nicely! Thanks.